# Processor.init() called multiple times for a single task in Kafka Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use a processor that leverages a `WALL_CLOCK_TIME` punctuation, and I've noticed that after the rebalance phase the `init()` method gets called more than once for the same task.

I log this line in `init()`:

```
log.info("In processor init, taskId is {}, cancellable is {}", context.taskId(), statisticsSending);
```

And in the logs I can see that it was called twice:

> 07:53:15 INFO - In processor
>   init, taskId is 1_0, cancellable is
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationSchedule$RepointableCancellable@11a53ebd
>
> 07:53:15 INFO  - In processor
>   init, taskId is 1_0, cancellable is
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationSchedule$RepointableCancellable@7770d7b7

Also, I log what's happening in the `close()` method, and I saw that a `Cancellable` was being cancelled there...

> 07:53:15 INFO - Closing cancellable
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationSchedule$RepointableCancellable@11a53ebd

...and judging from its identity hashcode (11a53ebd), the existing processor had been reused, but a new one was created as well. As a result, my periodic task has been scheduled twice, instead of once.

I thought that there would be only one processor per task. Any ideas what might have caused such behavior and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During rebalance, all `Processor` are closed and later initialized again after the rebalance. This is required to make sure no data is lost.

However, the hash you see refers to the registered punctuation, but not the `Processor` object. Thus, if you `cancel` the punctuation in `close` and `schedule` a punctuation in `init()` the old schedule will be replaced by a new schedule.

Comment: But from what I've observed, the `init` is executed twice in a row after rebalance. So the order was: init -> close -> init -> init. That double init perplexed me. Is this normal? If not, I think I can make a MCVE to show it, because in the project I was working on it was happening on a consistent basis, and I had to guard against that behavior.

Comment: I see. Than you are hitting a minor bug that was fixed in upcoming 1.1 release: https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/bce8125dcf5a87ed29bbe795cd7591d45bdf3d9a

Comment: Yeah, looks like so. Thanks! I've tried to reproduce it, but a minimal app no longer had these issues.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: Is this still valid? I see when restarting Kafka streams (using low-level API), then, init() is called multiple times. Can you please suggest when this was resolved?

Comment: The minor fix from above is in `2.0.0` (and newer) releases, as you can see from the tags of the commit.